# Update under the hood

Tags: postgresql

Does update query execute delete query in postgres?

Comment: I think update just changes the existing data instead of delete and reinserting every affect row

Comment: `UPDATE` is effectively `DELETE` + `INSERT` in Postgres. See Bruce's excellent [MVCC presentation](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/mvcc.pdf) for details.

Comment: @NickBarnes thank you!

Comment: @NickBarnes: to be precise: the `update` only creates a new row version (but only if HOT is not effective). The "delete" part is handled much later during vacuum. So the update itself is "only" an insert

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yeah, an `UPDATE` doesn't actually "delete" anything, but it does the same thing that `DELETE` does, i.e. it expires the old row and leaves it for vacuum to clean up.